# Download in batch with wget and modify files with a python script immediately after download

Tags: python, bash, wget

I want to download climate data from the [CHELSA](https://chelsa-climate.org/) database.

One way to do so programmatically is to use wget, following their guidelines:

> Download the file (envidatS3paths.txt), install wget and then run the command: `wget --no-host-directories --force-directories --input-file=envidatS3paths.txt` .

However, for each file that are downloaded, I would like to perform a operation on them (basically, trimming the data because they are quite big).

I looked at the wget manual, but I could not find anything related to an intermediary script to run inbetween downloads.

I could possibly run a second background command to finds any new downloaded file and trim it, but I wonder if the first solution could be more straightforward.

Comment: How about just using python to download the files sequentially and process them?

Comment: Damn, you're right. I think I asked about bash because CHELSA doc pointed to it, but yes I guess I could do everything in Python. I'll let the question live as such though, because I'm still curious how I could solve that in bash. But yeah with Python it should be quite easy.

Comment: @WaterFox I'm at the same point as you were a few years back. Do you still have the python code to download and crop CHELSA files and would you be willing to share it?

Comment: Hi @mabe ! I actually wrote a small python package for that. You can find it on Pypi https://pypi.org/project/quetzal-crumbs/1.0.17/ and then have a command line invocation as shown in https://github.com/Quetzal-framework/quetzal-CRUMBS/blob/main/tests/integration.sh. If you use this in your own research, you can cite the library as in https://europepmc.org/article/ppr/ppr492474
I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! I've found some fishy trends in temperature and precipitation in the daily CHELSA time series in a remote region I need it for (relic from reanalysis?). I'll have to figure out, if I can at all use the data set.

Comment: Ok good luck! If you need anything feel free to open an issue on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run a for loop over the input file and for each file run `wget -O $new_file_name $url`

try something like this -

bash

```
for url in $(cat envidatS3paths.txt); do wget -O $(echo $url | sed "s/\//_/g").out $url  ; done
```

python

```
for url in opened_file:
    subprocess.Popen(f'wget -O {url.rsplit('\')[1]} {url}')
```